Error when linking the flutter application with Firebase
enter image description here
I am tried:
1-Clean and Rebuild
2-Update Gradle Version
Check Dependencies and Libraries:
Ensure that any third-party libraries or dependencies you’re using are compatible with Gradle 9.0.
If a library is causing compatibility issues, consider finding an alternative or checking for updates.

I have the same issue, it seems the flutter project and the SDKs are in different partitions of the hard disk
just go to the project root and run flutter clean then go to the android folder and delete
the .gradle folder then back to the project root and run flutter pub get
and rebuild the app.
